# CSS animations: Fading images into one another and animating the image and moving it's direction

Tags: css, image, carousel, css-animations, keyframe

I'm working on cloning the AirBnB website for practice working with React. I am attempting to copy the website's jumbotron and it's functionality.

On [AirBnB's website](https://www.airbnb.com/) the jumbotron images fade into one another. The images also slowly float upwards while they are displaying. I am having trouble emulating this.

I am attempting to use a CSS Keyframe like this:

```
    @keyframes fader {
  0% {
    background: url('./components/layout/images/jumbo1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
  16.67% {
    background: url('./components/layout/images/jumbo2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
  33.34% {
    background: url('./components/layout/images/jumbo3.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
  50.01% {
    background: url('./components/layout/images/jumbo4.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
  66.68% {
    background: url('./components/layout/images/jumbo5.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
  83.35% {
    background: url('./components/layout/images/jumbo1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
  100% {
    background: url('./components/layout/images/jumbo2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
}



.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.gallery {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation: fader 30s linear infinite;
  height: 500px;
}
```

This creates the image gallery and swaps images every few seconds but I can't figure out how to get each image to fade as it switches to the next image or how to animate the image so that it floats upwards while it is displaying.

How can I do this? Can I apply more than one Keyframe to the same element? [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Nicknyr/Airbnb) is the CodeSandbox if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure by what you mean by "animate the image so that if floats upwards while it is displaying", but I can share with you the keyframes that I use to allow a images to fade in and out. I hope that this helps you. You can apply the CSS class to that section of content, or utilize your preferred method to institute this keyframe. Once you have the fade-in-out animation set, assuming this isn't a slide-show and the images just fade-in-out on-load after a duration of time.

```
 @keyframes fadeinout {
    0%   { opacity:1; }
    17%  { opacity:1; }
    25%  { opacity:0; }
    92%  { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

I noticed the title of this question is "fading images into one another", if you mean that one image changes to another (in CSS we mean that this set of images would be on 'top of each other' in position:absolute;, you will need to set the :nth-of-type(n) selector to have an animation delay on the children. So if you had a set of 3 images you wanted to fade out you would use the below.

```
#slideshow img:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
#slideshow img:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
    -o-animation-delay: 4s;
    animation-delay: 4s;
}
#slideshow img:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```